# Regex matching dates in a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Following up from this thread, im trying to make this work

JavaScript regular expression to match X digits only

```
string = '2016-2022'
re = /\d{4}/g
result = [...string.matchAll(re)]
```

This returns an array of two arrays. Is there a way to consolidate this into 1 array?

However it doesn't look like this is returning the desired results

I'm new to regular expression. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *This returns an array of two arrays. Is there a way to consolidate this into 1 array?* `[...string.matchAll(re)].flat()`. If the structure is set `'2016-2022'.split('-')` might be an alternative.

Comment: can you make this the answer? I can mark it as correct

Comment: _"Is there a way to consolidate this into 1 array?"_ -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), e.g. _"Yes, you can map or loop through the match results with for-of to build your own array."_ as mentioned on your [previous, quite similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71797198/javascript-regex-match-4-digits)

Comment: @Morgan Allen: Added it for the time being.

Comment: Does this still need attention?

Answer (score 0):

this return an array of matches

```
result = string.match(re)
```

Comment: I need to use matchAll, not just match

Comment: Why do you need to use matchAll?

Answer (score 0):

This is a function to parse the string encoding those two year values and return the inner years as items of an array:

```js
let o = parseYearsInterval('2016-2022');
console.log(o);

function parseYearsInterval(encodedValue){
  var myregexp = /(\d{4})-(\d{4})/;
  var match = myregexp.exec(encodedValue);
  if (match != null) {
    let d1 = match[1];
    let d2 = match[2];
    //return `[${d1}, ${d2}]`;
    let result = [];
    result.push(d1);
    result.push(d2);
    return result;
  } else {
    return "not valid input";
  }
}
```

I think there are better ways to do that like splitting the string against the "-" separator and return that value as is like:

```js
console.log ( "2016-2022".split('-') )
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = '2016-2022';
var result = [];
str.replace(/\d{4}/g, function(match, i, original) {
    result.push(match);
    return '';
});
console.log(result);
```

I also wanted to mention, that [matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) does basicly nothing else then an while exec, that's why you get 2 arrays, you can do it by yourself in a while loop and just save back what you need

```js
var result = [];
var matches;
var regexp = /\d{4}/g;
while (matches = regexp.exec('2016-2022')) result.push(matches[0]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Add a `console.log()`.

Comment: Your second snippet does not terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a split if you know that only years are in the string and the strucutre isn't changing:

```
let arr = str.split("-");
```

Answer (score 0):

### Question

> ```
> string = '2016-2022'
> re = /\d{4}/g
> result = [...string.matchAll(re)]
> ```
>
> This returns an array of two arrays. Is there a way to consolidate
> this into 1 array?

### Solution

You may simply [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the result of `matchAll`.

```js
let string = '2016-2022'
let re = /\d{4}/g
console.log([...string.matchAll(re)].flat())
```

### Alternative

If your structure is given like **"yyyy-yyyy-yyyy"** you might consider a simple [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
console.log('2016-2022'.split('-'))
```